# Calculadora de sistemas de ecuaciones lineales 3x3 no funciona

Tags: c++, matrices

Estoy haciendo un programa que calcule las soluciones de ecuaciones lineales por método de gauss, ya escribí todo el código y según yo, ya debería funcionar pero cuando mando a calcular las incógnitas me dice que las incognitas = nan, revisé muchas veces el planteamiento del las ecuaciones para "x", para "y" y para "z", y nada me ha servido, podrían ayudarme?
Este es el código, solo puse la parte del codigo a partir de la cual se empiezan a calcular las soluciones:

```
factor = sistema[1][0] * (-1); //Factor que va a multiplicar a fila [0] despues
factor_dos = sistema[0][0]; //Factor que va a multiplicar a fila [1] despues

for(int j=0; j<=3; j++){
    sistema[0][j] *= factor; //Multiplicación de la fila 0 por el factor
}

for(int j=0; j<=3; j++){
    sistema[1][j] *= factor_dos; //Multiplicación de la fila 1 por el factor
}

for(int j=0; j<=3; j++){
    sistema[1][j] += sistema[0][j]; //Suma de las filas para volver [1][0] = 0
}
//Hasta acá el elemento [1][0] = 0

factor = sistema[2][0] * (-1); //Factor que va a multiplicar a fila [0] despues
factor_dos = sistema[0][0]; //Factor que va a multiplicar a fila [2] despues

for(int j=0; j<=3; j++){
    sistema[0][j] *= factor; //Multiplicación de la fila 0 por el factor
}

for(int j=0; j<=3; j++){
    sistema[2][j] *= factor_dos; //Multiplicación de la fila 2 por el factor
}

for(int j=0; j<=3; j++){
    sistema[2][j] += sistema[0][j]; //Suma de las filas para volver [2][0] = 0
}

//Hasta acá el elemento [1][0] = 0 y el elemento [2][0] = 0
//Ahora se quiere convertir el elemento [2][1] a 0

factor = sistema[2][1] * (-1); //Factor que va a multiplicar a fila [1] despues
factor_dos = sistema[1][1]; //Factor que va a multiplicar a fila [2] despues

for(int j=0; j<=3; j++){
    sistema[1][j] *= factor; //Multiplicación de la fila 1 por el factor
}

for(int j=0; j<=3; j++){
    sistema[2][j] *= factor_dos; //Multiplicación de la fila 2 por el factor
}

for(int j=0; j<=3; j++){
    sistema[2][j] += sistema[1][j]; //Suma de las filas para volver [2][1] = 0
}
//Ahora [2][1] = 0, se puede proceder a calcular las incognitas

cout<<"\nLa matriz es:\n";
for(int i=0; i<=2;i++){ 
    for(int j=0; j<=3;j++){
        cout<<sistema[i][j]<<"  ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

z = sistema_dos[2][3] / sistema_dos[2][2]; //Calculo de 'z'
sistema_dos[1][2] *= z; //Reemplazo de z en fila 1 para poder calcular 'y'
suma = sistema_dos[1][3] - sistema_dos[1][2];
y = (suma) / (sistema_dos[1][1]); //Calculo de 'y' conociendo 'z'
suma = sistema_dos[0][3] - sistema_dos[0][1]*y - sistema_dos[0][2]*z;
x = (suma) / (sistema_dos[0][0]); //Calculo de x conociendo 'y' y 'z'

cout<<"El valor de 'x' es: "<<x<<endl; 
cout<<"El valor de 'y' es: "<<y<<endl; 
cout<<"El valor de 'z' es: "<<z<<endl; 

    getch();    
     return 0;
     }
```

Bueno agradezco de antemano cualquier crítica constructiva, apenas estoy aprendiendo lo básico. Que cosas podría mejorar? se puede hacer de una manera más sencilla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La variable `sistema_dos` no se está actualizando, necesita ser actualizada porque es la matriz que contiene las soluciones de las ecuaciones lineales y es una copia de la variable `sistema`. Y la variable `sistema`, al ser la matriz original que contiene las ecuaciones lineales, será modificada durante el método de eliminación de Gauss y necesita modificar los valores para convertirse en una matriz triangular.

La actualización de `sistema_dos` ocurre porque es la matriz que contiene las soluciones de las ecuaciones lineales.

**(** *método de eliminación de Gauss*  **)**

Aquí tienes el método de eliminación de Gauss:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

 double sistema[3][4] = {
    {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0},
    {2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0},
    {3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 6.0}
  };

  double sistema_dos[3][4];

  // 1 - va a inicializar la matriz sistema_dos 
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      sistema_dos[i][j] = sistema[i][j];
    }
  }

  //  eliminación de Gauss : sistema_dos, será una matriz triangular superior
  for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
    for (int i = k + 1; i < 3; i++) {
      // Calcula el factor de multiplicación
      double factor = sistema_dos[i][k] / sistema_dos[k][k];

      // Actualiza la fila i con el factor de multiplicación
      for (int j = k; j < 4; j++) {
        sistema_dos[i][j] -= factor * sistema_dos[k][j];
      }
    }
  }

  // calcula las incógnitas
  double z = sistema_dos[2][3] / sistema_dos[2][2];

  sistema_dos[1][2] *= z;

  double suma = sistema_dos[1][3] - sistema_dos[1][2];
  double y = suma / sistema_dos[1][1];

  suma = sistema_dos[0][3] - sistema_dos[0][1] * y - sistema_dos[0][2] * z;
  double x = suma / sistema_dos[0][0];

  cout << "El valor de 'x' es: " << x << endl; 
  cout << "El valor de 'y' es: " << y << endl; 
  cout << "El valor de 'z' es: " << z << endl; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow amigo muchas gracias no entiendo muy bien como funciona el ciclo for que hace la eliminación de gauss, podrías explicarme? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Lo que él hace es dividir cada línea del sistema lineal por su coeficiente y luego restar los múltiplos de las líneas que ya están reducidas de las líneas que quedan. De esta forma, el coeficiente de cada línea se convierte en 1 y los demás son 0.

Comment: Wow, no sabía que existía ese métodon muchas gracias cardosource!!!.